# Split document by pages from 2 to 7 into a new document each page

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am triying to write a code (macro) in word, where I can define the range as pages and copy the pages from 2 to 7 in a new document?

```
Sub SaveSelected()

 Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=2
    Set rgePages = Selection.Range
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=7
    Documents.Add , wdNewBlankDocument
    Range.Paste
    ActiveDocument.Save
    
End Sub
```

In the moment I have the issue that the code doesn`t work.

1. define the pages as range
2. copy the range
3. open a new (.docx)
4. save as window (pop-up)

Comment: Please note that *"doesn`t work"* is no useful error description. You need to tell what is wrong. Which error do you get and where in the code, or what does your code do versus what did you expect it to do.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

To save all pages in range to a new document

```
Sub SaveSelected()
   Dim newDoc As Document
   Dim src As Range
   Dim pages As Range
   
   'set src range to start at page 2
   Set src = ActiveDocument.GoTo(what:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=2)
   'extend range to the end of page 7
   Set pages = ActiveDocument.GoTo(what:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=7)
   src.End = pages.GoTo(what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page").End
   Set newDoc = Documents.Add(, wdNewBlankDocument)
   newDoc.Content.FormattedText = src.FormattedText
   'remove extra paragraph at end
   With newDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range
      If Len(.Text) = 1 Then .Delete
   End With
   newDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Delete
   newDoc.Save 
End Sub
```

To save each page in range to new document

```
Sub SavePages()
   SavePageToNewDocument ActiveDocument, 2, 7
End Sub

Sub SavePageToNewDocument(SourceDoc As Document, FirstPage As Long, LastPage As Long)
   Dim pageNum As Long
   Dim srcPage As Range
   Dim footer As Range
   Dim newDoc As Document
   
   For pageNum = FirstPage To LastPage
      Set srcPage = SourceDoc.GoTo(what:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=pageNum)
      srcPage.End = srcPage.GoTo(what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page").End
      Set footer = srcPage.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
      Set newDoc = Documents.Add(, wdNewBlankDocument)
      'take across text and formatting
      newDoc.Range.FormattedText = srcPage.FormattedText
      With newDoc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
         .FormattedText = footer.FormattedText
         'remove extra paragraph at end
         With .Paragraphs.Last.Range
            If Len(.Text) = 1 Then .Delete
         End With
      End With
      'remove extra paragraph at end
      With newDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range
         If Len(.Text) = 1 Then .Delete
      End With
   Next pageNum
End Sub
```

An alternate method to get the new document as an exact copy of the original complete with page layout.

```
Sub SavePageToNewDocument(SourceDoc As Document, FirstPage As Long, LastPage As Long)
   Dim pageNum As Long
   Dim srcPage As Range
   Dim footer As Range
   Dim newDoc As Document
   
   For pageNum = FirstPage To LastPage
      Set srcPage = SourceDoc.GoTo(what:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=pageNum)
      srcPage.End = srcPage.GoTo(what:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\page").End
      Set footer = srcPage.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
      'create new document from the saved version of source document to get page layout
      Set newDoc = Documents.Add(SourceDoc.FullName)
      newDoc.Content.Delete
      'take across text and formatting
      newDoc.Range.FormattedText = srcPage.FormattedText
      'remove extra paragraph at end
      With newDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range
         If Len(.Text) = 1 Then .Delete
      End With
   Next pageNum
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Timothy thank you very much.

I have just two more questions.

1. It doesn`t copy the same formatting (for an example line spacing)

2. the footer is also missing? (number of pages etc.)

Do you know how to take those things also to the new doc?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: @SAUNACLAN - to add the footer you need to know which of the three footers you need and then add that to the document. See edited answer. `.FormattedText` includes both text and formatting.

Comment: An other question I want to write as first in the code that "it should remove the protection". Is there an option to remove the protection in the beginning and add it in the end of the code?

Comment: @SAUNACLAN - when you ask a question you need to include ALL the relevant detail. See documentation: [`Document.Unprotect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.unprotect), [`Document.Protect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.document.protect)